# Как реализовать работу слайдера в разных секциях на странице

Tags: javascript, слайдер

Помогите, пожалуйста, поправить js код работы слайдера.
Реализовал логику переключения слайдов. Но она работает только для первой секции. В остальных секциях слайдер не работает. Необходимо, чтобы слайдер работал и на остальных экранах.

В коде секции представлены блоками screen-1 (-2, -3 и т.д., слайдер представлен блоком image-gallary.

При нажатии на превью изображения image-gallary-preview__item соответствующему полноразмерному изображению image-gallary-fullview-item добавляется класс image-gallary-fullview-item_active.
Связь превью и полного изображения осуществляется через атрибут data-fullvie на элементе image-gallary-preview__item.

Пробовал поместить логику в цикл forEach, но что-то не работает.

```js
/*
 * Toggle image-gallary
 **/

const imageGallary = document.querySelector('.image-gallary ');
const imageGallaryFullviewItems = imageGallary.querySelectorAll(
  '.image-gallary-fullview-item',
);
const imageGallaryPreviewItems = imageGallary.querySelectorAll(
  '.image-gallary-preview__item',
);

imageGallaryPreviewItems.forEach(previewItem => {
  previewItem.addEventListener('click', handleImageGallaryPreviewItemsClick);
});

function handleImageGallaryPreviewItemsClick() {
  toggleImages.call(this);
}

function toggleImages() {
  // remove image-gallary-fullview-item_active class from all image-gallary-fullview-item
  imageGallaryFullviewItems.forEach(fullviewItem =>
    fullviewItem.classList.remove('image-gallary-fullview-item_active'),
  );
  // find linked fullview image by date-tab attribute and add image-gallary-fullview-item_active class
  imageGallary
    .querySelector('.' + this.dataset.fullview)
    .classList.add('image-gallary-fullview-item_active');
}
```

```css
.list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.screen__image-gallary {
  width: 296px;
}

.image-gallary__fullview {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.image-gallary-fullview-item {
  width: 296px;
  height: 212px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.image-gallary-fullview-item {
  display: none;
  background-color: #777;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 13px 0px #00000099;
}

.image-gallary-fullview-item_active {
  display: block;
}

.image-gallary-fullview-item__image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 212px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.image-gallary__preview {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.image-gallary-preview__item {
  width: 68px;
  height: 49px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: rgb(170, 45, 81);
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: brightness(0.8) drop-shadow(0 0 0 transparent);
  transition: transform 0.2s linear, filter 0.2s linear;
  &:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    filter: brightness(1) drop-shadow(2px 4px 6px black);
  }
}

.image-gallary-preview__item:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  filter: brightness(1) drop-shadow(2px 4px 6px black);
}

.image-gallary-preview__image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 49px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<section class="screen-1" id="location">
  <!-- image-gallary -->
  <div class="image-gallary screen__image-gallary">
    <ul class="image-gallary__fullview image-gallary-fullview list">
      <li class="image-gallary-fullview__item image-gallary-fullview-item image-gallary-fullview-item_1 image-gallary-fullview-item_active">1-fullview</li>

      <li class="image-gallary-fullview__item image-gallary-fullview-item image-gallary-fullview-item_2">2-fullview</li>

      <li class="image-gallary-fullview__item image-gallary-fullview-item image-gallary-fullview-item_3">3-fullview</li>

      <li class="image-gallary-fullview__item image-gallary-fullview-item image-gallary-fullview-item_4">4-fullview</li>
    </ul>

    <!-- image-gallary-preview -->
    <ul class="image-gallary__preview image-gallary-preview list">
      <li class="image-gallary-preview__item" data-fullview="image-gallary-fullview-item_1">1-preview</li>

      <li class="image-gallary-preview__item" data-fullview="image-gallary-fullview-item_2">2-preview</li>

      <li class="image-gallary-preview__item" data-fullview="image-gallary-fullview-item_3">3-preview</li>

      <li class="image-gallary-preview__item" data-fullview="image-gallary-fullview-item_4">4-preview</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- image-gallary-preview -->
  </div>
  <!-- image-gallary end -->
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var thisElement;
var data;
var removeClass;
document.querySelectorAll('.image-gallary-preview__item').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', e => {
    thisElement = e.currentTarget;
    data = e.currentTarget.dataset.fullview;
    removeClass = thisElement.closest('.image-gallary').querySelectorAll('.image-gallary-fullview-item')
    removeClass.forEach(fullviewItem =>
      fullviewItem.classList.remove('image-gallary-fullview-item_active'),
    );
    thisElement.closest('.image-gallary').querySelector('.' + data).classList.add('image-gallary-fullview-item_active');
  });
});
```

```css
.list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.screen__image-gallary {
  width: 296px;
}

.image-gallary__fullview {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.image-gallary-fullview-item {
  width: 296px;
  height: 212px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.image-gallary-fullview-item {
  display: none;
  background-color: #777;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 13px 0px #00000099;
}

.image-gallary-fullview-item_active {
  display: block;
}

.image-gallary-fullview-item__image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 212px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.image-gallary__preview {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.image-gallary-preview__item {
  width: 68px;
  height: 49px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: rgb(170, 45, 81);
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: brightness(0.8) drop-shadow(0 0 0 transparent);
  transition: transform 0.2s linear, filter 0.2s linear;
  &:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    filter: brightness(1) drop-shadow(2px 4px 6px black);
  }
}

.image-gallary-preview__item:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  filter: brightness(1) drop-shadow(2px 4px 6px black);
}

.image-gallary-preview__image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 49px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<section class="screen-1" id="location">
  <!-- image-gallary -->
  <div class="image-gallary screen__image-gallary">
    <ul class="image-gallary__fullview image-gallary-fullview list">
      <li class="image-gallary-fullview__item image-gallary-fullview-item image-gallary-fullview-item_1 image-gallary-fullview-item_active">1-fullview</li>

      <li class="image-gallary-fullview__item image-gallary-fullview-item image-gallary-fullview-item_2">2-fullview</li>

      <li class="image-gallary-fullview__item image-gallary-fullview-item image-gallary-fullview-item_3">3-fullview</li>

      <li class="image-gallary-fullview__item image-gallary-fullview-item image-gallary-fullview-item_4">4-fullview</li>
    </ul>

    <!-- image-gallary-preview -->
    <ul class="image-gallary__preview image-gallary-preview list">
      <li class="image-gallary-preview__item" data-fullview="image-gallary-fullview-item_1">1-preview</li>

      <li class="image-gallary-preview__item" data-fullview="image-gallary-fullview-item_2">2-preview</li>

      <li class="image-gallary-preview__item" data-fullview="image-gallary-fullview-item_3">3-preview</li>

      <li class="image-gallary-preview__item" data-fullview="image-gallary-fullview-item_4">4-preview</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- image-gallary-preview -->
  </div>
  <!-- image-gallary end -->
</section>

<section class="screen-2" id="location2">
  <!-- image-gallary -->
  <div class="image-gallary screen__image-gallary">
    <ul class="image-gallary__fullview image-gallary-fullview list">
      <li class="image-gallary-fullview__item image-gallary-fullview-item image-gallary-fullview-item_1 image-gallary-fullview-item_active">1-fullview</li>

      <li class="image-gallary-fullview__item image-gallary-fullview-item image-gallary-fullview-item_2">2-fullview</li>

      <li class="image-gallary-fullview__item image-gallary-fullview-item image-gallary-fullview-item_3">3-fullview</li>

      <li class="image-gallary-fullview__item image-gallary-fullview-item image-gallary-fullview-item_4">4-fullview</li>
    </ul>

    <!-- image-gallary-preview -->
    <ul class="image-gallary__preview image-gallary-preview list">
      <li class="image-gallary-preview__item" data-fullview="image-gallary-fullview-item_1">1-preview</li>

      <li class="image-gallary-preview__item" data-fullview="image-gallary-fullview-item_2">2-preview</li>

      <li class="image-gallary-preview__item" data-fullview="image-gallary-fullview-item_3">3-preview</li>

      <li class="image-gallary-preview__item" data-fullview="image-gallary-fullview-item_4">4-preview</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- image-gallary-preview -->
  </div>
  <!-- image-gallary end -->
</section>
```

Comment: Благодарю вас. Все заработало. Но, единственно, я хотел бы разбить кода на части - функции. Разделил кода на части (мне так легче для понимания). У меня удаляется класс active, но не добавляется. [ссылка](https://codepen.io/monsara/pen/wvBqPxX)

Comment: Так вы не прописали .classlist.add)) Вы закончили ваше действие тем что просто нашли необходимый блок где нужно добавить класс, а то что его необходимо таки добавить как-то упустили)

Comment: Благодарю. Поправил, все заработало. Здесь (код)(https://codepen.io/monsara/pen/wvBqPxX?editors=0010), который работает на сайте (все отлично), но в codepen тоже самое выдает ошибку в консоли. Я так понимаю, в codepen не читается this. Подскажите почему так происходит?

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите

```
const imageGallary = document.querySelector('.image-gallary ');
```

Указывает на первый найденный элемент. Чтобы работало как надо нужно обработать все, по очереди.

Например поместить весь js-код в функцию gallery, например:

```
function gallery(el) {
    const imageGallary = document.querySelector(el);
    ...
}
```

И дальше создавать по экземпляру, хоть в цикле, хоть руками

```
let g1 = gallery('.screen-1');
let g2 = gallery('.screen-2');
```

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/p93nzca4/) Тут в консоль выводится инфа, о том, что обрабатывается.

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, на этом примере. У меня убирает класс active, но не добавляет его

Comment: Поместил сюда, но происходит то, что описал const imageGallarys = document.querySelectorAll('.image-gallary');
  console.log(imageGallarys);

  imageGallarys.forEach(gallary => { ...  }
  });

Comment: Извините. Все получилось. Хочу пройтись циклом. Как мне выбрать все галлереи const gallarys = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="screen-"]'); Не получается

Comment: Почему не получается с помощью document.querySelectorAll('[class^="screen-"]'); ? Проверил, получает массив элементов

Comment: При попытке вызвать функцию через цикл в консоли появляется ошибка. Посмотрите, пожалуйста [ссылка](https://jsfiddle.net/g42k30rL/)

Comment: Вы пытаетесь передать элемент в качестве класса для поиска. Надо просто брать элемент. Как вариант https://jsfiddle.net/Lwqn0vft/

Comment: Благодарю!  Это то, что я хотел сделать!